# Node is null even though it has a value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures

I'm trying to make a binary search tree based on an array of integers.

I've created a function BST that takes an array and its size as a parameter. Now I'm calling another function makeBST on every item of the array that takes the root node and that value. It creates another node and attach it with the root node based on the value.

**But the makeBST function is not recursing over itself and executing the NULL condition for every value of the array, even though root node is not null**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

class Node {

    public:
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

Node *newNode(int x){

    Node *node = new Node();
    node->data = x;
    node->left=NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
};


void makeBST(Node *node, int x){

    if(node==NULL){
        // keep getting executed even though root node has a value.
        // here must be error.

        cout << " NULL condition " << endl;
        node = newNode(x);
        return;
    };
    if((node->data) > x){
        cout << "also working" << endl;
        makeBST(node->left,x);
    }else if((node->data) < x){
        makeBST(node->right,x);
    };
};

Node *BST(int arr[], int n){

    Node *root = newNode(arr[0]);
    for(int i=1; i<=n-1; i++){
        cout << "loop" << i << endl;
        makeBST(root,arr[i]);
    };
    return root;
};

int main(){

    int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int n=10;
    Node *root = BST(arr,n);

    return 0;
};
```

I know this is not the best way of creating Binary search tree. But I'm a beginner and this is what i could come up with.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `node = newNode(x);` in `makeBST` does nothing but leak memory. You are changing the _local_ value of the `node` pointer variable, but that change is not seen at the call site. When you call `makeBST(p, x)` with `p == nullptr`, `p` will still be `nullptr` afterwards. Try `Node*& node` for the `makeBST` argument instead. Then make sure to understand why that works.

Comment: Also, the `;` after each `if (...)  { ... }` is not needed. And you have to `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: Other than the actual problem at hand, may I ask why you use a class like a structure? Your `newNode` function looks like it should be the constructor of `Node` instead, and `makeBST` also feels like a method.

Comment: @MaxLanghof what do you mean? Not using ';' will delete the temporary space created in if else condition? I'm a beginner so please pardon my knowledge.

Comment: @Aziuth no particular reason for that buddy, I just used those as a function. As i said no particular reason :)

Comment: Aside: your tree in the example is also a list, you only assign `Node *right`s

Comment: `if (something) { doSomething(); };` is exactly the same as `if (something) { doSomething(); }` (note the lack of `;` at the end). There is no "temporary space created", I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently, you are changing the local value for (*node) in the function without have any effect on the variable `node` passing to it. You should read about passing pointers as value vs. as reference.

If you want to change `node` you need to pass it as reference:

```
void makeBST(Node **node, int x) {

    if(*node==NULL){
        cout << " NULL condition " << endl;
        node = &newNode(x);
        return;
    };
    if((*node->data) > x){
        cout << "also working" << endl;
        makeBST(&(*node->left),x);
    }else if((*node->data) < x){
        makeBST(&(*node->right),x);
    };
};
```

Make sure you pass the address of the node when calling `makeBST`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But I've one question. I've studied about pass by value and pass by reference. While appending a node in a linked list we only pass the head node by value like `head` and accept it in the append function as `Node *head` still the new node gets appended in the list successfully. Why don't we pass `&head` instead, I mean `&head` would work but so does `head`? It would be helpful if you answer this.

Comment: @PrateekGautam - when a function changes a member of the object you get, for instance, if the function gets `head` and changes the value of `head->left` it's ok to get `head` by value. On the other hand, when you need to change the object itself, for instance, when you are getting `head` and want to replace `head` you have to get it by reference or you will just change the function-scope `head`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it now.